# OpenGL drawFrame method controlling rendering or not?

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es

Using Android and OpenGL I call a drawFrame(GL10 gl) method that is drawn when the system is ready to render another frame.

In a separate game loop thread I control the updating and collision detection test.

I have a camera following an object that is at rest with the ground. The object is pulled down by an acceleration force but the object detects its collision with the ground and positions itself back to where it should be.

Because I have two threads, when the simulation is simply sitting there, sometimes the render thread draws the object when it is pulled below the ground, before the collision detection system has time to reposition the object. The result is a camera that wobbles up and down occasionally at random times.

I've read that you can control when the drawFrame method is called and this would fix my problem, but I've heard that you shouldn't do that either. Why should I not do that and what is a way to fix my problem?

Comment: I believe this question boils down to making sure that both threads don't execute at the same time. I would rather control it in someway.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid the render thread 'sneaking in' before all of the updates (physics & collision) are done. This should be solved by using synchronized.

If you lock the whole thing down however, you have the update thread waiting for all of the rendering to finish and vice versa, which is not a good idea. Therefore I would suggest having a 'copy' of the variables you're updating around for the rendering thread to use.
In some cases (e.g. when you're updating vertex positions) these copies are implicit on the GPU. In other cases (e.g. your camera position), you'll have to explicitly define them.

To illustrate what I mean:

```
update() {
  synchronized(lock) {
    doPhysics()
    doCollision()
  }
}

draw(GL gl) {
  synchronized(lock) {
    transferToGLVariables()
  }
  render(gl)      
}
```

This way you don't have to control when the render thread renders at all, which I believe is a more robust approach.